# Design pattern to replace repetitive code when changing properties of one object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 4 custom spinners which modify the width, height, X location and Y location of one selected widget. My widget can be dragged around the screen, and the idea is to use these spinners to change certain properties such as width or height, and see immediate effect on the changes.
Is there a pattern that I can use to replace all these classes (XSpinnerListener, YSpinnerListener...) with only one and indicate which property of my current object (a JButton) needs to change? Is this a good design approach?

```
public void init(){
    widthSpinner.setListener(new WidthSpinnerListener());
    heightSpinner.setListener(new HeightSpinnerListener());
    xSpinner.setListener(new XSpinnerListener());
    ySpinner.setListener(new YSpinnerListener());
}


public class XSpinnerListener implements SpinnerListener {

    @Override
    public void spinnerValueChanged() {
         current.setLocation(xSpinner.getValue(), current.getY());
    }
}

public class YSpinnerListener implements SpinnerListener {

    @Override
    public void spinnerValueChanged() {
        current.setLocation(current.getX(), ySpinner.getValue());
    }
}

public class WidthSpinnerListener implements SpinnerListener {

    @Override
    public void spinnerValueChanged() {
         current.setSize(widthSpinner.getValue(), current.getHeight());
    }
}

public class HeightSpinnerListener implements SpinnerListener {

    @Override
    public void spinnerValueChanged() {
         current.setSize(current.getWidth(), heightSpinner.getValue());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Comment: This is _very_ close to being subjective. Please try to make it as purely objective as possible. There are certain accepted patterns and antipatterns, but if this isn't one, this is very subjective.

Comment: Please edit the question as you wish if you believe that it is not up to the standards. Basically instead of having 4 listeners each for one separate widget which modifies something, I want to have only one, and tell it which property to modify and how

Comment: You could add a parameter to your spinner listener constructor, such as an enum, that identifies which spinner is listening. Then in your listener code, switch on the enum to see which of the 4 actions you take.

Answer (score 6):

Some musings...

You could emulate Swing's design by giving your SpinnerListener `spinnerValueChanged(...)` method a SpinnerEvent parameter, one that indicated which axis is being changed. The Axis could be encapsulated by an enum,...

```
enum Axis {
   X("X"), Y("Y"), WIDTH("Width"), HEIGHT("Height");

   private String name;

   private Axis(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

}
```

And the SpinnerEvent parameter class could look something like:

```
class SpinnerEvent {
   private Object source;
   private Axis axis;
   private int value;

   public SpinnerEvent(Object source, Axis axis, int value) {
      this.source = source;
      this.axis = axis;
      this.value = value;
   }

   public Object getSource() {
      return source;
   }

   public Axis getAxis() {
      return axis;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }

}
```

Your SpinnerListener interface (which you don't show us) would have to change:

```
interface SpinnerListener {
   public void SpinnerValueChanged(SpinnerEvent e);
}
```

And perhaps your concrete implementations could work on objects that implement a Movable interface:

```
interface Movable {

   public abstract int getX();
   public abstract void setX(int x);
   public abstract int getY();
   public abstract void setY(int y);
   public abstract int getWidth();
   public abstract void setWidth(int width);
   public abstract int getHeight();
   public abstract void setHeight(int height);
   public abstract void move(Axis axis, int value);
}
```

with a key method, move that could be implemented like so:

```
@Override
public void move(Axis axis, int value) {
  switch (axis) {
  case X:
     x += value;
     break;
  case Y:
     y += value;
     break;
  case WIDTH:
     width += value;
     break;
  case HEIGHT:
     height += value;
  default:
     break;
  }
}
```

Small concrete implementation

```
class ConcreteSpinnerListener implements SpinnerListener {
   private Movable movable;

   public ConcreteSpinnerListener(Movable movable) {
      this.movable = movable;
   }

   @Override
   public void SpinnerValueChanged(SpinnerEvent e) {
      movable.move(e.getAxis(), e.getValue());
   }

}
```

Comment: Not happy with X("X"), Y("Y"), WIDTH("Width"), HEIGHT("Height"); what if we have 1 million listeners? This enum is going to get very big.

Comment: @Andrei: The number of enum items should not be proportional to the number of listeners but rather to the number of dimensions. Please update your question to fully define the complete problem space, as this will impact on all potential solutions. Thanks.

Comment: I mentioned in the title the property of an object. The number of properties can be unlimited. The example I added, was from something I worked on. I believe I wrote too much and there is a more elengant way to do this. Also, what if we have to add a listener which changes the name or the text of this object (i.e., a widget). There are at least 3 different classes which need to edited to accommodated this change.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would rather add the `move(…)` method to the Axis enum itself – this way the enum can implement the cases you need a switch statement for. Your `move(…)` method then becomes `e.getAxis().move(movable)`

Answer (score 3):

In similar situations, I always perform all of the operations whenever something changes if there are no performance penalties:

```
public void init(){
    SpinnerListener spinnerListener = new MySpinnerListener();
    widthSpinner.setListener(spinnerListener);
    heightSpinner.setListener(spinnerListener);
    xSpinner.setListener(spinnerListener);
    ySpinner.setListener(spinnerListener);
}

public class MySpinnerListener implements SpinnerListener {
    @Override
    public void spinnerValueChanged() {
         updateLocationAndSize();
    }
}

void updateLocationAndSize() {
    current.setLocation(xSpinner.getValue(), ySpinner.getValue());
    current.setSize(widthSpinner.getValue(), heightSpinner.getValue());
}
```

This way the code is shorter and the intention is clear to other readers.

Also, another advantage of this approach is that it is easier to synchronize initial state of action triggers (spinners) with action consumers (`current` component).

It may or may not be applicable or beneficial in your example, but suppose that you are opening the screen with saved size and location attributes for the `current`. You initialize the spinners with the saved values, then you invoke `updateLocationAndSize` to synchronize `current`'s size and location with the spinners, and then register the listener to be notified of the incremental changes.

Comment: I think this approach introduces some overhead, because if you change the value of any of those spinners, you need to execute the other 3 instructions in your updateLocationAndSize().

Comment: True, but the overhead is negligible. Think of the `setLocation` method, it's the same principle, you set both coordinates, although you just rewrite one with the same value. The `Component` API designers didn't want to trade the readability of the API and implementation for a negligible performance gain which could be obtained by setting only one coordinate. Actually, if you look at `setLocation`, `setSize`, `setWidth` and all of the similar `Component` methods, you'll notice that they all delegate to `reshape(int x, int y, int width, int height)`.

Comment: You could improve my solution by invoking `setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)`. I actually edited my answer to contain two invocations instead of four. Also I think that invoking `setLocation` and `setSize` separately is more readable than calling `setBounds` with four parameters. In the answer, I focused on a more general description of the approach to similar problems; each specific case can of course be further improved if needed.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. However, I'm not happy with this approach of updating or checking for updates from all widgets. Besides the fact that this creates some extra overhead, it can be any type of listener which needs to change other properties of the object. Let's say we have 1 million listeners. How are we going to group all of them.

Comment: In such an extreme case, you would have no choice but to balance between readability and performance. If you had 1 million listeners, then your application would probably be unusable because thousands of them would have bugs. You would probably have to group the functionalities into 1000 listeners each doing 1000 operations, although many of the operations would be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Java 8 and accepting for the moment that your spinners actually have a `setListener()` method, I would just implement `SpinnerListener` as a single concrete class that takes advantage of lambdas. Noticing that each of your `SpinnerListener`s invokes a method on current that takes two `int` arguments, one could envision something like this in SpinnerListener:

```
BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> currentSetter;
Supplier<Integer> firstArg;
Supplier<Integer> secondArg;

public void spinnerValueChanged() {
    currentSetter.accept(firstArg.get(), secondArg.get());
}
```

It could be invoked in init like this:

```
public void init() {
    widthSpinner.setListener(
        new SpinnerListener(
            { a, b -> current.setSize(a, b) },
            { widthSpinner.getValue() },
            { current.getHeight() }));
    // ... etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of design, your main problem seems to be isolation of the view from the controls. You are looking for Model View Controller I think.

The model is what is called `current`in the OP.

If setting X position is a primary model operation, there should be a `setXLocation(int x)` in the API of current.

If this is true, all four actions are one liners that associate a slider with the appropriate action, using an interface as the Java <= 1.7 way of passing function pointers around, so you're fine as is. I'd make the listeners anonymous probably (keep the actual code called close to the Slider definition if it is not reused) but that is just stylistic.

Basically, we are mixing view (the slider itself) and control (the listener code) a bit, but it's OK in most cases in my opinion (I'd go with that in your example, and stick to your current solution). Readability is still pretty good, though it's verbose. That's just Java, it will run fine and be maintainable in my opinion (as much as any GUI is).

If you have a lot of such properties to edit, or the API of the model is good already and does not need these fine controls, you might want to go with an explicit controller, i.e. a class that interprets fine grain actions `setXLocation(x)` and delegates them appropriately on the actual current object `setLocation(x,current.getLocY())`.

The full blown scheme in that direction is suggested in Hovercraft's answer already :  make your Commands explicit (per the DP), have view elements generate commands, and a controller to interpret them. You need a pretty heavy use case to go down that path, although ultimately it is more robust and extensible. And GUI don't really have performance issues if you are not doing anything stupid. So Dragan's answer also strikes me as pragmatic and sensible. In a way it already partially isolates the control code from the view in the actual setLocationAndSize method.

To summarize, if the code you are putting in your listener is a one liner, you are fine from design standpoint.

If the listener code is complex, it should not be "hidden" in a Listener : this produces code fragmentation, a lot of duplication in various listeners, the important code is hidden in GUI code when it should never be the case.

For more than one-liners, get the listener delegate the actual action to a more complex controller, or consider extending the model API to include this operation as a high level service it offers.

Comment: Can you provide some code to explain your point? Also, it could be one liner or can be more, and I know it works as the way it is right now and from a design point of view. However, I'm not happy with creating different listeners.